# Review of dual coil latching relay driver with single input

Tags: automotive, latching-relay, review

I need to drive dual coil latching relays from a single input signal. Following are my assumptions:

- low-side drive of the coil
- coils connected to 12V automotive
- coil resistance unknown, assumed 1A will be more than sufficient
- input floating -> 12V (automotive) transition generates a set pulse
- input 12V -> floating transition generates a reset pulse
- automotive 12V load dump is limited to 40V with 5.0SMDJ24A
- pulses generated are ~100 ms

This is the schematic I arrived at:

[image]

Datasheets:

- [SN74AHC123ADR](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn54ahc123a)
- [MCP1416](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002092G.pdf)
- [IRLML0040TRPbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML0040-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664894825e4)
- [TPS7B6950DBVR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7b69.pdf?ts=1679906341327&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FTPS7B69%252Fpart-details%252FTPS7B6950DBVR)
- [5.0SMDJ24A](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=48cdd48e-0d63-4244-9051-3c38b81cacda&filename=test-item-with-attachement)

I would greatly appreciate if somebody had the time to review the schematic.

Comment: The MCP1416s are probably unnecessary, given the low gate charge of the IRLML0040 and undemanding circuit conditions. You probably want a pull-down resistor on the FET gates, though, to ensure predictable startup behaviour.

Comment: need a pull-down on the input.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Hearth I checked that the MCP1416 had predictable startup behaviour. I thought that was sufficient. But of course, a floating mosfet gate when the entire gaget is without power is probably not ideal either. Thanks.